# Displaying the output of the ruby command .pack("H*")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, hex, pack

I have a Rails project which requires working with and manipulating Hex strings.  At certain stages I want to print my string for troubleshooting and testing.  But I'm getting weird strings in my output.  For the following example, I am using Rails 3.1.3 and ruby 1.9.3p385.

Rails console:

```
["A"].pack('H*')
=> "\xA0"
["0A"].pack('H*')
=> "\n"
["54"].pack('H*')
=> "T"
```

Run the same commands but this time output it using a *puts* command:

```
puts ["A"].pack('H*')
?
=> nil
puts ["0A"].pack('H*')

=> nil
puts ["54"].pack('H*')
"T"
=> nil
```

How come for ["A"] and ["0A"] when I try to print the results using the *puts* command it doesn't display the same as just running the command without printing it?  And how come ["54"] works correctly?

**UPDATE**

Above I said that `puts ["0A"].pack('H*')` isn't displayed correctly but that is not true.  `["0A"].pack('H*')` returns a newline byte so when you run `puts ["0A"].pack('H*')` it correctly display the newline byte in string format which appears as nothing but is actually correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`irb` uses the `inspect` method to produce strings to show and `["A"].pack('H*').inspect` is `"\xA0"`. `puts` calls `to_s` on its arguments to convert them to strings, `String#to_s` doesn't do anything useful (unless returning `self` is useful) so:

```
puts ["A"].pack('H*')
```

is trying to print the byte `\xA0` which doesn't represent anything printable in whatever encoding your terminal is expecting (probably UTF-8 these days but maybe ISO-8859-1 or Windows-CP-1252) so you get the standard "I don't know what this is" question mark. `puts` works fine with `["0A"].pack('H*')` and `["54"].pack('H*')` because they produce printable characters.

Comment: You are right, and I wasn't - I deleted my comment. It's probably something to do with output encoding rather than string encoding itself; `puts "ü".encode('Windows-1252')` also displays `?` even though it is a valid string.

Comment: @Amadan I (hopefully) clarified that bit anyway, unstated assumptions aren't a good idea.

Comment: @muistooshort - i figured it was because that byte just couldn't be displayed properly but didn't understand the reason behind it and now I do.  Thanks for the explanation and clearing up the  confusion.